# AES256 Issue using swift 5

Tags: node.js, swift, encryption, aes, node-crypto

I am using `AES256` algorithm `CBC mode` with `pkc7` padding. I have backend in `Node.js`. But getting first 12 random characters.

**Here is my swift code:**

```
    func encrypt(data: Data, key: Data, iv: Data) throws -> Data? {

        // Output buffer (with padding)
        let outputLength = data.count + kCCBlockSizeAES128

        var outputBuffer = Array<UInt8>(repeating: 0,
                                        count: outputLength)
        //var outputBuffer: [UInt8] = []
        var numBytesEncrypted = 0
        let status = CCCrypt(CCOperation(kCCEncrypt),
                             CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES),
                             CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding),
                             Array(key),
                             kCCKeySizeAES256,
                             Array(iv),
                             Array(data),
                             data.count,
                             &outputBuffer,
                             outputLength,
                             &numBytesEncrypted)

        guard status == kCCSuccess else { return nil }

        let outputBytes = iv + outputBuffer.prefix(numBytesEncrypted)

        return Data(bytes: outputBytes)
    }
```

How can I do without padding? Or what should be done from backend?

[image]

Comment: Are you encrypting in swift or decrypting? How does the nodejs do the crypto?

Comment: @JamesKPolk I am encrypting from swift and decrypting from node.js

Comment: It's probably your encoding.  Make sure you are using the same encoding on iOS for converting the text to bytes as you do to convert the bytes to text.  The fact that you have some resemblance of the data shows that the encryption did what it was supposed to do.  If the encryption failed, it would have blown up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tags **before and after** payload you want to share. That tag will be your headers.

like **`<tag>string</tag>`**

So if you encrypt you will get first 12 random bytes

so you need to ignore text other than between `**<tag>...</tag>**`

Comment: Do we need to ignore from backend side?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with what you posted, you probably just got some parameter incorrect somewhere between Swift and node.js.

First of all it's a good idea to check that you can decrypt locally, in the same language, whatever you encrypted. Using information from the screenshot you posted (note for the future: also post everything in text, typing in base 64 encoded data from a screenshot far more tedious than copy and paste).

In your case, in Swift, that would look like this:

```swift
import UIKit
import CommonCrypto

var key = "zewQjVQMGdoEJK0yHtLcbP3ZlHOKjERG"

// This is the ciphertext with the initialization vector prepended.
let base64String = "w93bonVuqtW22Drj4HtZ3zNtNSt+5OBMapGGHekLCFA="
var data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String)!
// Split out the initialization vector and ciphertext
var iv = data[0..<kCCBlockSizeAES128]
var ciphertext = data[kCCBlockSizeAES128..<data.count]


var outputLength = data.count
var outputBuffer = Array<UInt8>(repeating:0, count: outputLength)
var bytesDecrypted = 0

let status = CCCrypt(CCOperation(kCCDecrypt),
    CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES),
    CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding),
    Array(key.utf8),
    kCCKeySizeAES256,
    Array(iv),
    Array(ciphertext),
    ciphertext.count,
    &outputBuffer,
    outputLength,
    &bytesDecrypted
    )

print(String(bytes: outputBuffer.prefix(bytesDecrypted), encoding: .utf8))
// Optional("gmail.com")
```

Once you know that all is working well in the same language try it in the other. Now I don't know much about node.js, but going line-by-line through the Swift would lead to this:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto')

let keyString = 'zewQjVQMGdoEJK0yHtLcbP3ZlHOKjERG'
let key = Buffer.from(keyString, 'utf8')

let base64String = 'w93bonVuqtW22Drj4HtZ3zNtNSt+5OBMapGGHekLCFA='
let ivPlusCiphertextBuffer = Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64')

// Split out the initialization vector and the ciphertext
let blockSize = 16 // Don't know how to get this in Node.js so hard-code it
let iv = ivPlusCiphertextBuffer.subarray(0, blockSize)
let ciphertext = ivPlusCiphertextBuffer.subarray(blockSize, ivPlusCiphertextBuffer.length)

let decryptor = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv)
var plaintext = decryptor.update(ciphertext, 'binary', 'utf8')
plaintext += decryptor.final('utf8')

console.log(plaintext)
// gmail.com
```

So as long as you get the output of your Swift routines to the input of a node.js routine that looks something like my example above, you should be good to go!